# Python Pandas Bottom-Up Calculation Within Groups

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

Assume I have the following dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":range(1,10), "B":range(5,14), "Group": 
[1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3],"C":[0,0,10,0,0,16,0,0,22], "last":[0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1], 
"Want": [19.25,8,91.6,71.05,45.85,16,104.95,65.8,22]})
```

For the last observation per group, I have the following code:

```
def calculate(df):
if (df.last == 1):
    value = df.loc["A"] + df.loc["B"]
else:
```

for all other observation per group, the row value is calculated as follows:

```
value = (df.loc[i-1, "C"] + 3 * df.loc[i, "A"] + 1.65 * df.loc[i, "B"])
    return value
```

In simple english this is what I'm trying to do. For the last observation in each group, column `C` equals the sum of columns `A and B`

For all other observations, I would like to calculate the value of column `C` from the "bottom up" using the "else statement" above (which is there for a proof of concept).

To further clarify, these are the formulas for calculating the `Want` column for `Group 2` using excel: `F4="F5+(3*A4)+(1.65*B4)", F5="F6+(3*A5)+(1.65*B5)", F6="F7+(3*A6)+(1.65*B6)", F7="A7+B7".` There's some kind of "recursive" nature to it, which is why I thought of the "for loop"

I would really appreciate a solution where it's consistent with the first `if statement.` That is

```
value = something
```

rather than the function returning a data frame or something like that, so that I can call the function using the following

```
df["value"] = df.apply(calculate, axis=1)
```

Your help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It would be very helpful to see a completed column of desired values.

Comment: @Karnage Please see the updated df with the desired values. I tried to edit the question but it doesn't allow me
    df = pd.DataFrame({"A":range(1,10), "B":range(5,14), "Group": 
    [1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3],"C":[0,0,10,0,0,16,0,0,22], \
                   "last":[0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1], "Want": 
    [19.25,8,91.6,71.05,45.85,16,104.95,65.8,22]})

Answer (score 1):

Seems you need `np.where` with `shift`

```
np.where(df.last==1,df.A+df.B,df.A+1.65*df.B+df.C.shift())
Out[199]: array([  nan, 11.9 , 14.55, 27.2 , 19.85, 22.5 , 41.15, 27.8 , 30.45])
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I have updated the df to include the correct values. df = pd.DataFrame({"A":range(1,10), "B":range(5,14), "Group":[1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3],"C":[0,0,10,0,0,16,0,0,22], \
                   "last":[0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1], "Want":[19.25,8,91.6,71.05,45.85,16,104.95,65.8,22]})

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`df.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and [`df.rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html#pandas.DataFrame.rolling) to reach the goal.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":range(1,10), "B":range(5,14), "Group": 
[1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3],"C":[0,0,10,0,0,16,0,0,22], \
               "last":[0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1],
               "Want": [19.25,8,91.6,71.05,45.85,16,104.95,65.8,22]}).sort_index(ascending = False)
df = df.assign(FakeC = df['A'] + df['B']) #you can comment out this line then replace FakeC with A+B for the following expressions
df = df.assign(value = np.where(df['last'] == 1, df['A'] + df['B'], df['FakeC'].rolling(2, min_periods=1).sum() - df['FakeC'] + 3 * df['A'] + 1.65 * df['B']))
df = df.assign(final = np.where(df['last'] == 1, df['value'], df['value'].rolling(2, min_periods=1).sum() -  df['FakeC'].rolling(2, min_periods=1).sum() + df['FakeC']))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   A   B   C  Group    Want  last  FakeC  value   final
8  9  13  22      3   22.00     1     22  22.00   22.00
7  8  12   0      3   65.80     0     20  65.80   65.80
6  7  11   0      3  104.95     0     18  59.15  104.95
5  6  10  16      2   16.00     1     16  16.00   16.00
4  5   9   0      2   45.85     0     14  45.85   45.85
3  4   8   0      2   71.05     0     12  39.20   71.05
2  3   7  10      2   91.60     0     10  32.55   59.75
1  2   6   0      1    8.00     1      8   8.00    8.00
0  1   5   0      1   19.25     0      6  19.25   19.25
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. This is the updated df that includes the correct values df = pd.DataFrame({"A":range(1,10), "B":range(5,14), "Group":[1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3],"C":[0,0,10,0,0,16,0,0,22], \
                   "last":[0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1], "Want":[19.25,8,91.6,71.05,45.85,16,104.95,65.8,22]})

Comment: Thank you. I had considered your approach before. I think the only drawback is that you would have to "reverse" the "final" column in order to re-index the whole df. Thanks anyways

Comment: that is caused by rolling can't support negative window size. I think alternative solution is use `for in` loop to iter each `df.iloc` to implement sum(i, i+1)

Comment: You are right. That's why I considered the for loop in the original statement. Thanks anyways for your help

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt. I try to keep things as straight-forward as possible.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "A":range(1,10), 
    "B":range(5,14), 
    "Group": [1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3],
    "C":[0,0,10,0,0,16,0,0,22], 
    "want":[19.25,8,91.6,71.05,45.85,16,104.95,65.8,22],
    "last":[0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1]})

# Determine where the last-in-group value applies.
condition = df['Group'] != df['Group'].shift(-1)

# Calculate the alternative data.
alternate_formula = (3 * df['A'] + 1.65 * df['B'])

# Calculate C as either the 'last-in-group' function or the alternative function.
df['C'] = np.where(condition, df['A'] + df['B'], alternate_formula)

# Reverse the order of the dataframe, group by the 'Group' column, run a cumulative sum
# for each group and then resort the back to the original order.
df['C'] = df.sort_index(ascending=False).groupby('Group')['C'].cumsum().sort_index()

print(df)
```

I think it is usually preferable to use a vectorised approach than an iterative approach such as 'apply'.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts on this. Please see the updated df that includes the correct values: df = pd.DataFrame({"A":range(1,10), "B":range(5,14), "Group":[1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3],"C":[0,0,10,0,0,16,0,0,22], \
                   "last":[0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1], "Want":[19.25,8,91.6,71.05,45.85,16,104.95,65.8,22]})

Comment: @xyz reformulated the response based on the target. This solution requires that the index is originally in ascending order.